# React ,Axios,How to switch request url from 3urls

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

[axios api url](https://github.com/stevecyj/angular-addressbook-v1/blob/master/src/environments/environment.ts)

I'm using axios in a React project with php api. I want to test 3 apis like https//:api1, https//:api12, https//:api3
and I  wanna switch these 3 apis by droplist(select options)

could you give me some suggestions or guides, thanks

Comment: You mean to show a `select` with 3 items (for each api). When you select one of them, axios will make a call to the selected API?

Comment: yes, that is what I want, is it possible? or I need solve it by other methods?
thanks!

Comment: actually I made the same crud with Vue, Angular and React, maybe the solution could help me finish the 3 little projects.

Comment: It's possible and even not that hard. If you want me, I can show you.

Comment: I really want , I just start my JS journey from scratch. Maybe I could got some skill from your coding. thanks for it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is simple. You have an array of strings - api URLs.

Render `select` tag and populate `option`s children `map`ped from the array.

Use `onChnage` to listen to user changes the select, take the value and use `axois` to call the API.

I added a `pre` to show the result (to prove the point )

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

const apis = [
  "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1",
  "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2",
  "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=3"
];

export default function App() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState("");
  const onChange = async e => {
    const url = e.target.value;
    const data = await axios.get(url);
    setResponse(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select onChange={onChange}>
        <option key={-1}>Choose API</option>
        {apis.map(api => (
          <option key={api}>{api}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <hr />
      Response:
      <pre style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>{response}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-dust-ljr2c?file=/src/App.js

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck!